# make 2 images overlap

Tags: html, css

I am using JS to write HTML code where I need to display 2 images exactly overlapped.

The height and width of both are same.
What CSS properties can I use to do this?

Comment: "I am using JS to write HTML code"...hmmmmm?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010624/overlap-images-in-css

Comment: I'm so confused. You're using JavaScript to create two image elements that you want to display directly over each other?

Comment: @MetalFrog Sure, why not. If the top one has transparency, you can see some of the bottom one through it!

Comment: @MrLister I understand the concept now, the wording was just throwing me off. "Using JS to write HTML code... What CSS" etc.

Comment: @MetalFrog OK, sorry, I thought you thought what good would it do to draw two images in the same place...

Comment: @MrLister It's all good. I was trying to confirm what they were looking for while figuring out if I had a grasp on it. I was vague.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Play around with the css in this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zuZxD/

I used opacity to display the overlapping.

Answer (score 7):

Position relative on the container, and absolute on the images:

All of the above answers are missing the fact that you need to position a parent element with something other than static, or else you will be positioning them absolute to the browser window, which I presume you do not wish to do.

`position: absolute` will give your position in the container of the closest parent with some sort of positioning. So we give the parent `position:relative;` without declaring top or bottom, this way it will be 0px off from where it would normally be (i.e. no change, but still has `position` declared).

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAC+byy+byywAAAAAAQABAEAIBAABBAQAOw==" style="height:125px; width:125px;">
    <img class="hide" src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAADCQIzCQIywAAAAAAQABAEAIBAABBAQAOw==" style="height:125px; width:125px;">
</div>

#container{
    position:relative;
}
#container img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.hide:hover{
    opacity:0;   
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BLbhJ/1/

**Edit: Added your hide functionality**

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.imageoverlap{

position: absolute;
top:100px;

}
</style>
...
<div class='imageoverlap'>
image1
</div>
<div class='imageoverlap'>
image2
</div>
```

Try that :D

Comment: You would obviously change the `top` clause to where you want it, maybe using the `left` and `right` as well. Play around it with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you set position to absolute, you can control where you want to place it.

```
<style>
    #overlay{position:absolute; top:0px;}
</style>

<div id="layer1"><img src="img1.png"></div>
<div id="overlay"><img src="overlay_image.png"></div>
```

Now you need to position #overlay where you want it, by setting top and left positions, i.e., top:0px, left:300px;